# Add greek letter in a ggplot in rmarkdown for pdf (latex)

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, bookdown

I'm working in `Rmarkdown` to prepare some lectures. I would like the final document to be in pdf. I'm trying to plot scatterplots for different values of rho (greek letter) with `ggplot2` to illustrate correlation and what it may looks like. I would like each panel to have rho = r. Using UTF-8 encoding, I can produce the desired results in the isolated chunk or by knit in html. But if I knit in pdf, it won't work

Here is the code, I'm working on.

````
---
title: "TEST"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(ggplot2)
```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
set.seed(42)
n = 100
r = c(-.999, -.75, -.5, -.25, 0, .25, .5, .75, .999)
DATA = numeric()
P = numeric()
for(i in 1:length(r)){
  X = round(MASS::mvrnorm(n = n, 
                          mu = c(0,0), 
                          Sigma = matrix(c(1,r[i],r[i],1),2,2)),4)
  DATA = rbind(DATA,cbind(X,r[i]))
}

DATA = data.frame(DATA)
colnames(DATA) = c("Variable1", "Variable2", "Correlation")

P.labs = paste("\u03C1 = ",r)   # works in HTML, not in pdf
#P.labs = paste("$\\rho$ = ", r) # does not work
#P.labs = paste("\\rho = ", r)   # does not work
#P.labs = paste("rho = ", r)      # Resignation for pdf
names(P.labs) = r

ggplot(data = DATA, aes(x = Variable1,y = Variable2)) +
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(vars(Correlation), ncol = 3, labeller = labeller(Correlation = P.labs))

```
````

Here is the error I get.

```
Error in stri_replace_all_charclass(str, "[\\u0020\\r\\n\\t]", " ", merge = TRUE) : 
invalid UTF-8 byte sequence detected; try calling stri_enc_toutf8()
Calls: <Anonymous> ... stri_trim -> stri_trim_both -> stri_replace_all_charclass
```

Here is the html figure that I would like in pdf.

[image]

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using Unicode, you can use the "plotmath" expression via `label_bquote()`. Keep everything the same in your original code except the last statement:

```
ggplot(data = DATA, aes(x = Variable1,y = Variable2)) +
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(vars(Correlation), ncol = 3, labeller = label_bquote(rho == .(Correlation)))
```

Note that you need `==` to get a single equal sign in plotmath.  This produces the following plot; it should work in all output devices:
[image: screenshot]